# Zoom.us user interface is too big, how do i reset to normal size?

Tags: zoom-meeting

With lates updates, Zoom.us ubuntu client creates user interface with wrong scaling making all elements too big even with normal sized screens.

This is for 5.2.440215.0803 and some prior versions.

There is no hint on configuration/settings on how to reset it to normal behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Reddit question is correct. [Reddit Linux Client](https://www.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/hat5af/linux_client_ui_elements_too_large_after_update/)
To fix this edit your local configuration file.

```
~/.config/zoomus.conf
```

and change from true to false this entry

```
autoScale=false
```

Answer (score 3):

This showed up for me first when updating from 5.0.418682.0603 to 5.1.422789.0705, and it made the interface almost unusable since you loose so much screen real estate. It bothered me enough to submit a ticket, but still no response.

There was no "autoScale" setting in my config (on Debian), but changing

scaleFactor=1 to scaleFactor=0

returned to the old scaling. Oddly after restarting zoom, this setting was overwritten and is back to 1, but the interface size is still small as it once was.

(I wish these changes were actually listed in the release notes.)

Comment: on my case the autoScale=false does survive restarts, i've have continued using it without further issues. Se answer posted by me